# Can't route my input parameters to my controller action method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-controller

I'm having trouble passing my textbox data to a controllers action parameters.

I'm trying to get the url to look like:

```
http://localhost:51124/gifts?searchTerm=test
```

but when I enter in text into the text box I get a url that looks like:

```
http://localhost:51124/gifts
```

Here is the code I have for the route:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Gifts",
            "gifts",
            new { controller = "Gifts", action = "Search" });
```

here is the code for the page with the text box and button to submit the text box data:

```
<form method="GET">
     <input type="search" name="searchTerm"/>
     <input type="button" value="Search By Category" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Search", "Gifts")'" />
</form>
```

here is the code for the controller that I'm trying to pass data to unsuccessfully:

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchTerm = null)
    {
        var model = db.Gifts.ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

"searchTerm" never gets any parameter that I pass into the text box. It's always null.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the form? The query string will only exist if the form is a `GET`.

Comment: hi Rowan, I displayed the form tag around the two input tags for you.

Comment: The problem is that you aren't submitting the form - you are simply redirecting the windows to a location. I'd say *Stephen Muecke* is closest to the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

Create a form element in you view with an input (i.e. the search box) that has a name attribute matching the parameter and a submit button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Gifts") {
  <input type='text' name='searchTerm' value='' />
  <input type='submit' value='search' />
}
```

This will post back to the Search method in the Gifts controller, passing the vale of the search box to the parameter 'searchTerm'

Comment: I guess not. Good luck getting help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you have to build this with jquery.  add a class to the inputs to use as a selector

```
<input type="search" name="searchTerm" class="txtSearch" />
<input type="button" value="Search By Category" class="btnSearch" />
```

then in your script

```
$('.btnSearch').on('click', function(){
    var url = '@Url.Action("Search", "Gifts", new { searchTerm = "----" })'.replace("----", $('.txtSearch').val());
    window.location(url);
});
```

Comment: is there a more appropriate way to do display results from a search in a view? It seems to me that if I want to display results from a search on another page/view there would be a way to do it without jquery, but I'm new to MVC and still trying to understand the routing/controllers/actions.

Comment: I use jquery for all of my search results.  Instead of just redirecting you should also look at doing an ajax call and returning a partial view and showing your result in that partial view.  either on the form or using jquery popup the partial view.